# Aerospike keeps getting client timeout error

Tags: ubuntu, timeout, client, aerospike

I've installed locally an instance of Aerospike (1 node) on Ubuntu 14.04 that is unable to perform any operation besides "show" operations of aql (Aerospike Query Language) because of this error:

```
Error: (9) Client timeout: timeout=1000 iterations=1 failedNodes=0 failedConns=0
```

I even purged and re-installed Aerospike but nothing changed. I am actually testing it to see if it is reliable for production but this error makes me have second thoughts. Has anyone encountered this problem before, or might have any idea for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i actually found out that it was trying to create a cluster with another instance we were running for same testing purposes on the local network on the same subnet, and due to different configurations, all nodes caught in this would either get stuck at the error mentioned above or ERR_CLUSTER_ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the default host ('localhost') is probably not where your server is running. If it's on a different IP than 127.0.0.1, use `aql -h IP`. You can also test with telnet if you can get any response `telnet 127.0.0.1 3000`.